# Purpose of EDB sockets

Tags: wiring, socket

The plugs that are made for EDB sockets can be plugged into normal sockets as well, but normal plugs can't be plugged into EDB sockets. I'm pretty sure that they have the same voltage, as my devices with an EDB plug run just fine on normal sockets.

EDB sockets, mostly found in office buildings.
[image]

What is the purpose of EDB sockets?

Comment: Don't have a source on this for that particular socket but sometimes something like this is used to distinguish between a socket which is connected to a UPS and not everything is allowed to be hooked up to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.fam-oud.nl/~plugsocket/Danish2.html), this is unique to Denmark, and EDB denotes a socket that has extra filtering for equipment that might be sensitive to power-line noise, such as computer equipment.

I'm guessing that the filters may have limited current-handling capability, so the unique socket is used to prevent normal heavy loads from being plugged in. It would also prevent such loads from contaminating the other EDB sockets with noise.

Here in the US, all branch circuits, filtered or not, must support a minimum of 15A, so we don't need a special socket — we just color-code them to indicate filtering or other special treatment.

Comment: It seems you're reading a bit too much into that (filtering etc.) All that seems to suggest is it's common for UPS use. Wikipedia seems to agree that's mostly a computer power socket: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:DK_2-5a

Comment: Some Danish guy talking about it: https://youtu.be/qs8bPa2ex04?t=304

Comment: Dave's answer is correct. I live in Denmark, and know the rules for electric appliances. The main reason that the EDB sockets have been made, are to make sure that equipment like refrigerators and vacuum cleaners (anything with a motor actually) is on a separate line and will not send noise back into the power grid where the sensitive equipement (computers) are connected.

Comment: Oh, and EDB is an abbreviation for Elektronisk Data Behandling (electronic data processing)

Comment: In my experience the small cheap mobile phone chargers are a lot worse than motors.